# Assign openstack network to instance at create with fog

Tags: openstack, fog

I'm using fog to create an instance and want to specify a specific network to attach to.

In the Openstack environment I am using there are multiple networks defined, when the instance is created it attaches to all networks. Is there a way to use the create 'options' to restrict this?

I have tried to use "nic" or "net-id" as would be used in the nova command line utility, but no luck.

Here is an example of an equivalent Nova command that I'd like to do via Fog:

```
nova boot --user-data ./mytext --image my-image image-name --flavor my-flavor --nic net-id=e150d32a-a4b1-4a1d-a7a2-fa435d61aaaaa --nic net-id=7a445090-b1c6-4503-83df-7714daaaaa
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can specify different networks using the nics option.

i.e.,

```
fog_client.servers.create(name: 'test_net',
                          flavor_ref: 1,
                          image_ref: '...',
                          nics: [{ :net_id => '...'}, ...])
```